# SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

Tags: jquery, json

So I looked around stackoverflow and i see that this may have been asked before but I cannot wrap my head around the error. Hopefully you guys can help me out. I'm trying to add variables to a json api url, but i get the following error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

What am i missing? Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Temp</title>
      <style>
        html {margin:2em; font-size:2em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
        h1 {margin:0 0 0.2em; color:#369;}
        img {float:left; margin-right:1em;}
        ul {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
      </style>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <section>
        <h1>Current Weather for </h1>
        <div class="img" id="data-img"></div>
        <ul>
          <li><b>Conditions:</b> <span id="data-current"></span></li>
          <li><b>Temperature:</b> <span id="data-temp"></span>&deg;</li>
          <li><b>Humidity:</b> <span id="data-humidity"></span>%</li>
          <li><b>Wind Speed:</b> <span id="data-wind"></span>mph</li>
          <li id="zip"></li>
          <li id="country"></li>
          <li id="api"></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <script>
            var zipcode = '27560';
            var countrycode = 'us'; 
            var appid = '743b2a88b6a3f61bdc87dee740b1a716';
            
            $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+ zipcode +','+ countrycode +'&appid='+ appid +, function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                $("#data-current").text(data.weather[0].description);
                $("#data-temp").text(data.main.temp);
                $("#data-humidity").text(data.main.humidity);
                $("#data-wind").text(data.wind.speed);
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error);
            }); 
            $('#zip').append(zipcode);
            $('#country').append(countrycode);
            $('#api').append(appid);
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your getJSON statement has an extra `+` sign. Get rid of the + after `appid`.

```
$.getJSON(... + appid +, function(data){...});
```

Comment: Yep that was it. That was a mental brain fart on my part. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Phantom, please kindly mark this as the answer if this answered your question. :)

Comment: Marked, sorry for the delay :)